# How do I find all input fields inside a form and copy their values into textarea using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I want to add a couple of input fields (*name*, *age*, *location*, *status*, etc...) to my form.

When I click `submit` button, how do I get all the values inside a form and place them into a single textarea element, so that it's easy to copy? Thanks for the help!

My current code:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="txt">
    <button type="button" onclick="ShowText();">Submit</button>
</form>
<span id="show"></span>
<script>
    function ShowText(){
        var txt = document.getElementById('txt');
        var show = document.getElementById('show');
        show.innerHTML = txt.value;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `id` attributes of input fields in that particular case.

Add an `id` attribute to the `form`

```js
function ShowText(){
    // find each input field inside the 'myForm' form:
    var inputs = myForm.getElementsByTagName('input');
    // declare 'box' variable (textarea element):
    var box = document.getElementById('show');
    // clear the 'box':
    box.value = '';
    // loop through the input elements:
    for(var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++){
        // append 'name' and 'value' to the 'box':
        box.value += inputs[i].name + ': '+inputs[i].value+'\n';
    }
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name"/><br/>
    <input type="text" name="age" placeholder="Age"/><br/>
    <input type="text" name="location" placeholder="Location"/><br/>
    <input type="text" name="status" placeholder="Status"/><br/>
    <button type="button" onclick="ShowText();">Submit</button>
</form>
<p>Show:</p>
<p><textarea cols=30 rows=5 id="show"></textarea></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can display the text data in a paragraph and then can select it easily as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body> 

<h1>My Web Page</h1>

<p id="demo">A Paragraph</p>
<form>
    <input type="text" name="in01" id="txt1">
    <input type="text" name="in02" id="txt2">
    <button type="button" onclick="ShowText();">Submit</button>
</form>

<span id="show"></span>
<script>
    function ShowText(){
        var txt = document.getElementById('txt1').value;
        var show = document.getElementById('txt1').value;
        //window.alert(txt);
         document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt +" "+show;
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi bro, can i put the inputted texts on the bottom and put in the box so that its easy to copy. im gonna create multiple inputs. Thanks whats the code for that btw?

Comment: add a new input tag as: 
<input type="text" name="in03" id="txt3">
In the script use like this: 
document.getElementById("txt3").value = txt +" "+show;

Comment: Can i also put the generated text messages in a box so that i could just ctrl+c them? How bro.

Comment: you can use a richtextbox and use its text attribute.

Comment: Sorry bro but i don't understand can you give me an example of that code. Can you just post the whole code im just gonna you know try to find the solution on how to add other box for my texts. i just need the big box for the generated text i inputted so that i could copy it.